# SQL Error Regarding Foreign Key Restraint

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am currently getting the following error when trying to add to one of my tables:

> Error adding record: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: (INSERT INTO `Stock`(`StockID`,`ItemName`,`MinAmountRequired`,AmountInStock`,`Order? (Yes/No)`,`DataLastUpdated`,`OrderNumber`,`SupplierRefrence`,`PurchaseID`) VALUES (1,",0,0,",",0,0,0);)

Currently, This is how I have my tables set up:

1. Stock

   `CREATE TABLE Stock (
       StockID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
       ItemName    TEXT NOT NULL,
       MinAmountRequired   INTEGER NOT NULL,
       AmountInStock   INTEGER NOT NULL,
       Order? (Yes/No) TEXT NOT NULL,
       DataLastUpdated TEXT NOT NULL,
       OrderNumber INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       SupplierReference   INTEGER NOT NULL,
       PurchaseID  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       FOREIGN KEY(PurchaseID) REFERENCES Purchase(PurchaseID),
       FOREIGN KEY(OrderNumber) REFERENCES Orders(OrderNumber),
       FOREIGN KEY(SupplierReference) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierReference));`
2. Orders

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Orders (
     OrderNumber   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
     CustomerReferenceNumber   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     OrderDate TEXT NOT NULL,
     ItemName  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
   ```
3. Suppliers

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Supplier (
     SupplierReference INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
     Name  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     Address   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     ContactNumber INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);
   ```
4. Purchases

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Purchase (
     PurchaseID    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
     Date  TEXT NOT NULL,
     AmountSpent   REAL NOT NULL);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined these foreign keys in table `Stock`:

```
FOREIGN KEY(PurchaseID) REFERENCES Purchase(PurchaseID),
FOREIGN KEY(OrderNumber) REFERENCES Orders(OrderNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(SupplierReference) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierReference)
```

meaning that the values in columns `PurchaseID`, `OrderNumber`, `SupplierReference` need to reference values in columns of the tables `Purchase`, `Orders` and `Supplier`.
 
But you want to store 0 to all of these columns which I'm sure that is not the value of any of the referenced columns, since these referenced columns are defined as

```
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

and so their values are `> 0`. 
Pass valid values that do exist in these 3 tables and the statement will execute succesfully.

Comment: Also since StockID  on Stock is also PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, you don't need to pass 1 or any value. Remove it from the list and let the db engine assign a value to it.